# ¿ Como mostrar solo 2 decimales en los precios de WooCommerce mediante php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, users-roles

¿ Como puedo mostrar solo 2 decimales sin romper la función que añade texto a los precios ?

La tienda online esta enlazada con programa de inventario y fabricación, y Debido al redondeo de decimales de WooCommerce, nos producen errores a la hora de entrar los pedidos en el programa.

Esto lo solucionamos añadiendo 3 decimales en la configuración de WooCommerce, en "Opciones de Moneda"

El problema es que los precios con 3 decimales en la tienda quedan muy feos, son es agradable y queria cambiar para que se mostraran unicamente 2 decimales.

En parte lo hemos conseguido con la ayuda de un conocido el cual creo la siguiente función la cual filtra para dejar solo dos decimales en la tienda, sin afectar a la configuración de WooCommerce:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cambiar_num_decimales', 10, 2 );

function cambiar_num_decimales( $price, $product ) {
    $decimales = 2; // Número de decimales que deseas mostrar
    $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) ), array( 'decimals' => $decimales ) );
    return $price;
}
```

El inconveniente es que esta función, hace que solo se vean 2 decimales en la tienda, pero elimina el texto que tenemos añadido para diferenciar los precios, ya que tenemos 2 textos diferentes (P.V.P Y texto de mayorista: P.V.M.) porque la tienda vende a clientes mayoristas, los cuales tienen precios diferentes  al resto de usuarios.

Para mostrar el texto según el rol de usuario, tengo el siguiente código que funcionaba perfectamente:

```
function my_get_current_user_roles() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
      return $roles; // This will returns an array
  } else {
      return  array();
  }
}

function custom_price_message( $price ) { 
  global $post; 
  $product_id = $post->ID; 
  $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
  $textafter = "";
  if(!empty($roles)) { 
      if (in_array("wholesale_customer", $roles)) {
          $textafter = ''; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
      if (in_array("customer", $roles)  or in_array("administrator",$roles)) {
          $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
  }
  else{
      $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; // Or whatever you want
  }
    
  return $price . '' . $textafter . ''; //class textafter para el  

} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message');
```

Hice pruebas pero unicamente consigo que se elimine los precios o que se elimine el texto, por más que lo intento no funciona

¿ Como puedo corregir esto sin eliminar la funcionalidad de los textos?

Alguna de las opciones que he probado como esta, solo funciona con clientes normales, muestra 2 decimales y no elimina el texto de P.V.P,
Sin embargo para los clientes mayoristas no funciona, ya que cambia el precio de mayorista por el de minorista y tampoco añade el texto P.V.M  :

```
function my_get_current_user_roles() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
      return $roles; // This will returns an array
  } else {
      return  array();
  }
}

function custom_price_message( $price, $product ) { 
  $product_id = $product->get_id(); 
  $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
  $textafter = "";
  if(!empty($roles)) { 
      if (in_array("wholesale_customer", $roles)) {
          $textafter = ''; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
      if (in_array("customer", $roles)  or in_array("administrator",$roles)) {
          $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
  }
  else{
      $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; // Or whatever you want
  }
  $decimales = 2; // Número de decimales que deseas mostrar
  $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) ), array( 'decimals' => $decimales ) );
  $price_with_text = $price . ' ' . $textafter;
  return $price_with_text; 
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message', 10, 2);
```